# Obtener id más reciente laravel query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Trato de obtener el id más reciente dentro de un rango de ids.

| group_id | item_id | course_id | user_id | scoreTest | statusTest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 432 | **543** | 14 | 3 | 30 | Failed |
| 432 | 542 | 14 | 3 | 100 | Passed |
| 432 | 541 | 14 | 3 | 100 | Passed |
| 432 | 540 | 14 | 3 | 100 | Passed |
| 431 | **539** | 11 | 3 | 100 | Passed |
| 431 | 538 | 11 | 3 | 100 | Failed |

Como puedo obtener el id 543 de la columna item_id, tengo como 4 joins en mi tabla principal y esta tabla(item_views) es la que estoy tratando de acoplar a mi tabla principal,pra que me muestre los datos junto a los demás, per cuando ejecuto la consulta, barre los datos y toma de menor a mayor es decir toma el id 538 & 540 (los primeros id) y necesito que cuando barra tome el ultimo id los demas valores estan duplicados lo unico que cambia es ese id, y trato de obtner el más reciente:

```
$users_selector = GroupCourseUser::join('courses', 'group_course_user.course_id', '=', 'courses.id')
                ->join('group_user', function($join) {
                    $join->on('group_user.user_id', '=', 'group_course_user.user_id');
                    $join->on('group_user.group_id', '=', 'group_course_user.group_id');
                })
                ->join('users', 'group_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->join('groups', 'group_user.group_id', '=', 'groups.id')
                ->leftJoin('item_views', 'item_views.group_course_user_id', '=', 'group_course_user.id')
                ->leftJoin('items', 'items.id', '=', 'item_views.item_id')
                ->select(
                    'groups.id AS group_id',
                    'item_views.id AS item_view_id',
                    'groups.name AS group_name',
                    'courses.id AS course_id',
                    'courses.name AS course_name',
                    'users.id AS user_id',
                    'users.firstname',
                    'users.lastname',
                    'users.email',
                    'users.last_login',
                    'users.area_functional',
                    'courses.course_days',
                    'group_course_user.created_at',
                    'item_views.score AS scoreTest',
                    'item_views.status AS statusTest',
                ->where(function($q) use ($cid) {
                    if($cid != '0') {
                        $q->where('group_course_user.course_id', $cid);
                    } else {
                        $q->where('group_course_user.course_id', '!=', $cid);
                    }
                })->where('item_views.score','>','0.0')
                ->whereNull('group_course_user.deleted_at')
                ->whereNull('group_user.deleted_at')
                ->whereNull('courses.deleted_at')
                ->whereNull('items.deleted_at')
                ->orderBy('groups.id', 'asc')
                ->orderBy('courses.id', 'asc')
                ->orderBy('users.id', 'asc')
                ->groupBy(
                    'groups.id',
                    'groups.name',
                    'courses.id',
                    'courses.name',
                    'users.id',
                    'users.firstname',
                    'users.lastname',
                    'users.email',
                    'users.last_login',
                    'users.area_functional',
                    'courses.course_days',
                    'group_course_user.id',
                    'group_course_user.created_at',
                    'group_course_user.score',
                    'group_course_user.progress',
                    'group_course_user.finished_at',
                );
```

Intente con los sigs métodos y no funciono:

latest() X

take(1) X

orderBy('item_views.id','desc) X

el principal problema creo pueden ser los groupBy y los orderBy ya que el mismo query me devuelve siempre el item_id 538 pasa al sig registro y me trae 540, cuando debería ser 539 y 543 los ultimos agregados en ese orden, hay algun metodo que pueda usar?

Comment: ¿Cómo determinas cuál es el "id más reciente"? ¿El id más reciente siempre es el primer registro de resultados de tu query? Porque si así, puedes hacer `$users_selector->first()->item_id`

Answer (score 0):

cuando hagas la insercion usar

```
$last_id = DB::table('tabla_a_insertar')->InsertGetId([
   
'campo1' => $request->campoName,
'campo3' => $request->campoName2,

]);
```

y ya `$last_id` te devuelve el ultimo id, es decir el de tu insercion

Comment: No creo que esta termine de ser una solución del todo, por que si bien se trata de obtener el id mas reciente yo veo en el método `select` mas columnas